# Sharepoint - query article data externally

Tags: php, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I have a Sharepoint site set up, with a site collection that contains a publishing site for news.
News pages are based on the Article page layout, so contains title, date, byline, description, image, image alt, rollup image etc.

I've been looking at retrieving this information using a REST feed e.g.
servername/sites/sitecollection/news/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Pages

But this only returns title and date.  I need all the other fields too.

What is the best way (if there is one!) to retrieve this information so that I can pull it in to an external php site?

Comment: Hi Hameds. Yes I've had a quick look at them.  Can I filter the results e.g. select in rows of 10 (for pagination) and order the results?

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint is supposed to support OData so you can do things like $select=field1,field2.... as you can see on that [stack exchange post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58188/i-cannot-get-orderby-to-work-in-sps-2010-listdata-svc-rest-query)
however SP 2013 brings support for REST and OAuth which helps a lot in this kind of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser settings.  If it is only returning the title and date, it is probably because the browser you are using is treating the list as an RSS feed like Hameds brought up.  If you want to see the fields, turn off the RSS feed reading view. Like if you are using Internet Explorer go to the "gear" icon, Internet options --> content tab --> Feeds and web slices settings --> Uncheck the "Turn on feed reading view".  Then refresh your page.